# Python class attributes decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

not sure about the proper wording for that, but essentially what I would like to ask is if it is possible in python do something like this:

```
class Customer:
    self.name = 'Freddy'
    @reportMarketing
    self.surname = 'Krueger'
    self.eyes = 'Blue'
    @reportMarketing
    self.address = 'Elm Street'
    @reportAccounting
    self.tax_id = '8ab9a66cf'
    ...
```

where `@reportMarketing`  and `@reportAccounting` would be decorators (of sorts). The idea is that an instance like the one above could be then passed to some 'reporting class' that - based on whether the instance's attribute is decorated with `@reportMarketing` or a `@reportAccounting`, would then consider it for a specific 'reporting'. For instance, imagine you have customers database with instances like the one above, and you want data/attributes decorated with `reportMarketing` to be included in a report that goes to your marketing department, while the data/attributes decorated with `reportAccounting` to be included in a report that goes to your accounting department.

I guess conceptually, my question is can I even have decorators for attributes? I understand they are 'typically' (always?) meant for functions.

Also, to give more background, the classes I deal with have plenty of attributes (each), so going through all of them manually is quite error-prone, and so I thought dealing with it by simply decorating the couple of ones I'm after, is the cleanest and most extensible in the future.

Comment: `reportMarketing = ['surname', 'address']` and so on?

Comment: Decorator syntax is just a shorthand for function application. `self.surname = reportMarketing("Krueger")`, assuming that `reportMarketing` is defined to accept a string and return the same string, while having some other interesting or useful side effect. That said, the shorthand *only* applies to `class` and `def` statements, not assignments.

Comment: @chepner Meaning effectively there's no notion of attributes decoration? A class's methods (via the `def` which you mention) can be a 'subject' of an annotation, but not this class's attributes?

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner alredy pointed out in their comment, decorators don't apply to attribute assignments, only to `class` and `def` statements.

Independent of that, I find it a big hard to imagine how the decorators in your example would work, since they are functions called with the decorated class or definition as argument.

One method to have "labels" of sorts for your attributes is this:

```py
class Customer():
    attrs_reportMarketing = ('surname', 'address')
    attrs_reportAccounting = ('tax_id',)

    def __init__(self, name='', surname='', eyes='', address=''):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.eyes = eyes
        self.address = address
        self.tax_id = tax_id

def generate_Marketingreport(cust):
    report = {attr_name: getattr(cust, attr_name)\
              for attr_name in cust.attrs_reportMarketing}
    return(report)

customer1 = Customer(name='Freddy', surname='Krüger', eyes='blue',\
                     address='Elm_Street', tax_id='8ab9a66cf')

report1 = generate_Marketingreport(customer1)
# Produces a dictionary: {'surname':'Krüger', 'address':'Elm_Street'}
```

The way it works: The customer class defines fixed tuples which document which of its attributes should be included in particular reports. Whatever method generates the reports can access those and compile the respective attributes into a dictionary (or whatever else you'd do with them).
This will allow you do include the same attribute in more than one "report" group, and because `attrs_reportMarketing` are class attributes (defined with the class, not with the instance), you can even access them without any customer being defined, using e.g. `Customer.attrs_reportAccounting`. That sort of thing can be useful if a class has a lot of optional inputs, and you have some code that needs to figure out which of them need to be provided in order to allow certain functionality.

The same strategy can be expanded by specifying dictionaries as class attributes which contain useful information about the class. I find that sometimes useful if some generic code needs to create some object, but may have to select a (sub-)class dependent on the current situation, or if the code gets passed an object and needs to figure out how it needs to be handled. Example: your `person` class has a `customer` subclass and a `partner` one. All of them have names, but only the `customer` class has a `get_payment_history()` method, and only `partner`s have a `contact` attribute.

One word of caution, though: Hard-coding class attributes like this, in the source code, can also get messy. Depending on the complexity of the whole thing, it can be better to move this kind of information to a separate file, close to the input data, and separate from the code, because you might want to change the contents of your marketing report at some point, and wouldn't it be easier to do that by editing a report definition in a plaintext file, than having to wade through the hole source code to sift through all the classes that may or may not contain information that is relevant for marketing?

Then you could set up a small separate file like this:

```py
keys_marketingreport = {'cust': ('surname', 'address'),
                        ...}
```

...and have your report generator parse that, and know which attributes of the `cust` object instance it needs to include, and which attributes of whatever other inputs it may have available.